# Markpoint Print head width reset after reboot of printer

Tags: configuration, printers, thermal-printer

Currently I set the print head width and issue the !Z command. After this my value is configured in the printer but when I reboot the printer the value for the print head width gets reset to the value that it was set to before. I want the value to stay at the configured value, instead of getting reset after the reboot. Is there anything I am forgetting to do here?

Comment: Please add information such as your printer vendor and model, web accessible datasheets and user manuals, and software system, languages and libraries you are using.

Comment: By the way, for [this device](http://www.phoenixsupplies.co.uk/printhead-km2004a310a-for-markpoint-p-4636.html), isn't [this site](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) better?

Comment: I am not sure if the mentioned site is better. My question is about configuring the MP Nova6 printer using the [Programmer's Reference](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/226885/Datamax-Mp-Compact4.html#manual) which doesn't have anything to do with hardware related topics.

Comment: It would be difficult to give an answer or advice unless the details of the settings and commands sent by printing, the content of the problem, and what you want it to be correct are described.

Answer (score 0):

```
!V38153
```

Use the command to set the correct value of printer width here (`!Y8 832` or `!Y8 1280` or `!Y8 864` or other value).

```
!Z
```

```
restart /powerdown printer
```

Should work :)